# VB GetAsyncKeyState, combobox selected keys

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do an action, when specific keys, selected by the user, are pressed.. but I don't know how to do It.

Is there any easiest way to to this:

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "F8"
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F8) Then
        'something
    End If
ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "F9"
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F9) Then
        'something
    End If
ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "F10"
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F10) Then
        'something
    End If
End If
'and other more..
```

I tried

```
Dim asd as String
asd = ComboBox1.Text
If ComboBox1.Text Then
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.kj) Then
        'something
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to put everything in a `Dictionary`, using it you can check the specified keyboard key by the Dictionary key.

First, declare this at class level (outside any sub or function):

```
Dim Hotkeys As New Dictionary(Of String, Keys) From { _
    {"F8", Keys.F8}, _
    {"F9", Keys.F9}, _
    {"F10", Keys.F10} _
}
```

Then when you are going to check if the specified key was pressed you'd just do:

```
If GetAsyncKeyState(Hotkeys(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())) Then
    'Some code here
End If
```

---

To add more keys you just keep adding rows to the Dictionary.

```
{"<key alias>", Keys.<key value>}, _
```

`<key alias>` (without the `<>` brackets) must be **exactly** the same as the respective item in the `ComboBox`.

And a final note: every row should end with `}, _` except for the last one, which includes no comma `} _`.

Hope this helps!